# Underwater cameras

Tags: underwater

I have a Panasonic GX80 which I find great for photography as a hobby. I want to be able to take photos in the water of waves and surfers.
Are there any suggestions as to which cameras might be good to start off with? Obviously using my GX80 would be ideal as I like to have control of the settings. The housing is very expensive though. I would invest in it if  it is the best option in the long run.

Comment: @flolilolilo, that question is specifically asking about cameras for diving that can go down past 3m. Waves and surfers are at the surface. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to start with tough cameras. Currently one of the most flexible is Olympus TG5. It shoot still and video, can take RAW still and is good to 15 meters. Also you can buy housing for deeper challenges.